# Build and Deploy Code on STM32F4 Using Eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse, debugging, stm32, openocd

I had a problem while deploying code into my STM32F4Nucleo boards using Eclipse and I wanted to share the solution for public benefit. 
The problem is that the build process was working however when it comes to deploying the code into the microcontroller the system was stuck, further I was not able to debug the device. The step over and resume buttons were greyed out in the debug perspective.

Later I realized that it was due to the naming of the startup code of the MCU. For example in my case the name was,

```
startup_stm32f401xe.s
```

I forgot to capitalize the "s" in the extension of the file. When you rename it as,

```
startup_stm32f401xe.S
```

then recompile, both debugging and the code deployment issue was solved.

Just FYI, 
Bests

Answer (score 2):

Another way of doing so is modifying which file extensions are recognized as source files which then get compiled and linked. You can do so here on the workspace level:

[image]

or under project settings under C/C++ General -> File Types if you prefer to do so only for specific project(s).